# Check if string contains a-zA-Z characters or whitespace or empty?

Tags: regex

What is the regex Expression for this?

**Example:**

> 'New York' = true;
>
> '' = true;
>
> 'city' = true;
>
> '7' = false;
>
> '$' = false;

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z ]*$` this. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fC5gG5/1)

Comment: Try reading a tutorial.

Comment: `/^[^7$]*$/` qualifies. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQ2aV7/1). But seriously, read a tutorial.

Comment: @RadLexus: No numbers or special symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will check for `zero` or more characters in upper and lower case and space.

**Regex:** `^[a-zA-Z ]*$`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fC5gG5/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Down voter care to comment on what's wrong with approach or regex ?

Comment: I guess (I didn't downvote) that it's less a case of your answer being wrong but more a case of answering a bad/unclear question - which you shouldn't do, see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions

Comment: @SebastianProske: I get your point. Will keep in mind from next time. 
Jan: Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is `^[a-zA-Z ]*$`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the advice of reading a tutorial, you could come up with:

```
(?:^[A-Za-z\h]+$)|(?:^$)
# matches a-z in upper/lowercase and horizontal whitespaces
# or an empty line
```

Works only with `MULTILINE` mode, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hO5wI7/1).